# Apple Script:Find and replace not working

Tags: syntax-error, applescript

everybody, I am trying to make the user enter the name of the movie they want subtitles for and the for apple script to automatically search the subtitle website for the name of the movie they inputted.
To do this all of the spaces in the movie name need to be replaced to the + sign because urls convert spaces to the + sign. The code is not working an im getting the following errors:

1. Expected “end” but found “on”.
2. A “(” can’t go after this identifier.

Here is my code;

```
 on run

    display dialog "What's the name of the movie?" default answer " " with title "What's the name of the movie?" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    set moviename to text returned of the result
    set theText to moviename
    set theSearchString to " "
    set theReplacmentString to "+"

     end findAndReplaceInText(theText, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSearchString
    set theTextItems to every text item of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theReplacementString
    set theText to theTextItems as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theText
end findAndReplaceInText

 goToWebPage("https://rs.titlovi.com/prevodi/?prevod= & thetext")
 tell application "Safari"
 activate
 set URL of document 1 to theWebPage
 end tell
 end goToWebPage

end run
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Functions (handlers, in AppleScript speak) may not be nested in AppleScript. So you need to either move findAndReplaceInText and goToWebPage outside of `on run`, or merge their functionality into `on run` without using handlers.
2. Handlers begin with `on handlerName` and end with `end handlerName`; you have findAndReplaceInText beginning and ending with `end findAndReplaceInText`.

Here’s how it might work after separating the handlers:

```
on run
    display dialog "What's the name of the movie?" default answer " " with title "What's the name of the movie?" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    set moviename to text returned of the result
    set moviename to findAndReplaceInText(moviename, " ", "+")
    goToWebPage("https://rs.titlovi.com/prevodi/?prevod=" & moviename)
end run

on findAndReplaceInText(thetext, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSearchString
    set theTextItems to every text item of thetext
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theReplacementString
    set thetext to theTextItems as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return thetext
end findAndReplaceInText

on goToWebPage(theWebPage)
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        set URL of document 1 to theWebPage
    end tell
end goToWebPage
```

I’ve verified this code in Safari on Mac OS X 10.14.6.